# How to find all files in /etc beginning with P

Tags: command-line

I would like to know how to find all files in the /etc file beginning with P, which I will then store the results of in a new file.

So far I have

```
$find /etc -name
```

Unsure of what comes next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all regular files beginning with P, you can use:

```
find /etc -type f -name 'P*'
```

If you want to no recurse into subdirectories:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'P*'
```

Comment: Could this be modfied to avoid the results of subdirectories appearing?

Comment: for that, you need `-maxdepth` option. e.g., `find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'P*'`

Answer (score 0):

lets give `stat` a try:

```
  stat -c "%F %n" /etc/P* | grep "regular file" | cut -d' ' -f 3-
```

Comment: This will include any directories which start with P and their contents.

Comment: Now it wont... =)